# Connecting to a MSSQL server using LDAP on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, jdbc, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server, using a linux client.  I've tried both SQuirreL and DBeaver, but having no luck in either case.  I've tried a few different drivers.

The connection string I am given looks something like this:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://<server>:<port>/<database>,cn=OracleContext,dc=<specific_dc>,dc=<specifc_dc>,dc=<specific_dc>

This seems to be an invalid URL, and I've tried various combinations of things (like using jdbc:sqlserver:// ... protocol, etc.  It doesn't seem to like the @ldap in the connection string, and I've replaced the commas with semicolons.  But, I'm new to connecting to SQL Server, much less using LDAP.

Any thoughts/help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about sql-server but I'm pretty sure you can't connect to it using LDAP... LDAP assumes a hierarchical model (data is in a tree), while SQL assumes a relational model (data is in tables), the two are just too incompatible. So how does LDAP come into the picture?

Comment: I actually have no clue.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting the connection string.  (Though, that connection string is working for someone in a Windows environment.)

Comment: That connection string seems to be for connecting to an Oracle database. To connect to SQL Server you need a different connection string, as you can read in Microsoft documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using DBeaver the way to connect to the SQL Server Database with an AD user is using the jTDS driver.
I am using DBeaver 6.0 in Debian 9. The user is an AD user.

In order to connect to the SQL Server from Linux Debian using DBeaver

**1.- Select SQL Server jTDS driver**

[image]

**2.- Enter the connection information**

[image]

**3.- Go to Driver Properties tab and add the domain, user, password**
[image]

[image]

*Just as a note, in some post I found that they needed to change the property USENTLMV2 to TRUE but it worked for me either by putting the USERTLNMV2 in true or false.*

A problem that I found was that when I was trying to connect to the database using my user and password the next error was thrown:

[image: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.]

This error was thrown because of my user was about to expire. I tried with another AD user and it could connect.

Answer (score -2):

```yaml
cts:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbserver:1433;database=DB;domain=yourdomain.com;useNTLMv2=true
    driver-class-name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    username: username
    password: password
    hikari:
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      maximumPoolSize: 2
      minimumIdle: 1
```

Comment: compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jtds', name: 'jtds', version: '1.3.1'